# Compare images for finding the images are visibly same

Tags: python-3.x, image, comparison

Need to find the images are same , even if it has different resolution and size. No need of a pixel to pixel comparison, need to find all the images , texts, color etc. are same in the other image also.

Tried with different python packages to compare, but all are asking for same resolution. One of my image is screenshotted from Mac and other is from Ubuntu. Even both are same html, the contrast and resolution difference of the machines causing the images to become different when compare.

Tried.
Perceptual diff,
Image Hash etc.

•   PDIFFER – Python wrapper for perceptualdiff tool (https://pypi.org/project/pdiffer/)
Problem - pip install pdiffer failed to install in the Macs for the latest as well as old versions
•   NEEDLE - Installed needle (https://needle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) This one has an option to specify comparison engine to be perceptualdiff/Imagemagick instead of default PIL.
Problem Found - Has an option to save baseline image first and then run assertions on them. It works when baseline is saved and then compared. I didn’t find anything that would compare the screenshots with existing images.

•   OPENCV – Histogram based comparison. This converts images into grayscale, and into histograms and compares the histograms. Returns a value between -1 and 1 (-1 means not similar at all and 1 means highly similar) (https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/07/14/3-ways-compare-histograms-using-opencv-python/ )
Findings - I tested two images by converting into histograms and compared them Which returned a value of 0.8 (meaning somewhat similar).

Below code i tried using imagehash:

> from PIL import Image import imagehash
>
> image_one = 'result.png'
>
> img = Image.open(image_one) image_one_hash = imagehash.whash(img)
> print(image_one_hash)
>
> image_two = 'not-found-02.png'
>
> img2 = Image.open(image_two) image_two_hash = imagehash.whash(img2)
> print(image_two_hash)
>
> similarity = image_one_hash - image_two_hash print(similarity)

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far. Give us minimal working examples.

Comment: Edited , pls check

Comment: Imagemagick has a perceptual hash comparison. See http://www.fmwconcepts.com/misc_tests/perceptual_hash_test_results_510/index.html

Comment: Currently we are using is imagemagic, but its getting error when the images are from different machines depends on the pixel sizes and resolution.Imagemagic helps only to rely on one machine.

Comment: Hi there, have you found your solution?